# Shell script to move, archive and rename files

Tags: shell, date, unix

I am trying to move a bunch of files into a new directory, "archive" and then zip all these files, and renaming the zip onto "DD-MM-YYYY - DD-MM-YYYY", where the second DD-MM-YYYY is 7 days ahead of the first DD-MM-YYYY.

This is what I have done so far,

```
   CURRDATEforARCHIVE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
    mv /Source/path /Destination/path/inbound/
    mv  /Destination/path/inbound /Destination/path/$CURRDATEforARCHIVE
    cd /Destination/path/
    zip -r $CURRDATEforARCHIVE.zip $CURRDATEforARCHIVE
    rm -rf /Destination/path/$CURRDATEforARCHIVE
    mkdir /Source/path/inbound
```

But I think my implementation is rather clunky, not very clean. Is there a more "streamlined" manner to achieve it?

Comment: Does inbound exist before running this?

Comment: Yea it does. The implementation works, but I was wondering if there's a more better way of achieving the task.  Example, would it be better to create an empty folder at the archive location, and individually move the files over?

Comment: If mv /D.../path/inbound /D.../path/$C... is renaming, you could mkdir ...$C... first and mv /D.../path/inbound/* /S.../path/*  /D.../path/$C... IF there are no dotfiles (hidden files) to be zipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the second date is to use `date -d` with a relative time offset. Just create a second variable with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

CURRDATEforARCHIVE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
FUTUREforARCHIVE=`date -d "now + 7 days" "+%Y-%m-%d"`

echo "file_${CURRDATEforARCHIVE}-${FUTUREforARCHIVE}.zip"
```

**Output**

```
$ sh sevendays.sh
file_2015-07-12-2015-07-19.zip
```

You should also veriify you successfully created the `zip` file before removing the sources:

```
zip -r "$CURRDATEforARCHIVE.zip" "$CURRDATEforARCHIVE"

if [ -f "$CURRDATEforARCHIVE.zip" ] then
    rm -rf "/Destination/path/$CURRDATEforARCHIVE"
else
    printf "error: zip file creation failed '%s'\n" "$CURRDATEforARCHIVE.zip"
fi
```

**Note:** always `"quote"` your variable to protect against spaces in file names, etc..